# Oracle Char exceeds 255

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to create a table in Oracle with Char(300)? I read around and found this

> "..The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to
>   255.."

but I found that there are those created with CHAR(500). I am having an issue with "Field in data file exceeds maximum length" and the string to insert length is 499.

EDIT: The content of the control file:

```
options(skip=1,errors=999999,readsize=61640000,bindsize=61640000,rows=2000)
Load data
infile 'Hours_04.csv'
badfile 'Hours_04.bad'
truncate
into table XD_Hours
fields terminated by ";"  ENCLOSED BY '"' 
(   Name char,
    wdate Date "yyyy-mm-dd",
    hours decimal external,
    descr char(500),
    app char,
    hourstype,
    task Integer external,
    subproject Integer external,
    project Integer external,
    function char,
    organization char,
    fgroup char,
    HrsMod Date "yyyy-mm-dd"
)
```

Comment: That seems to have come from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html). The restrictions for Oracle RDBMS are not the same as for MySQL.

Comment: Don't use CHAR, use VARCHAR2. A CHAR is like a VARCHAR2 padded with spaces to the defined length (wasting space). There is hardly ever a reason to use a CHAR instead of a VARCHAR2.

Comment: The error seems to be coming from SQL*Loader. Perhaps showing your table definition (`create table` statement) and the control file would help. In the control file have you defined a field as just `CHAR`, rather than `CHAR(300)`?

Comment: Updated with a sample that requires CHAR(500). Could it be possible that single quotes caused problems? Or could it be some unicode or characters?

Comment: What is the table definition for `xd_hours`? Single quotes within the data won't be a problem. Multi-byte might; what is your DB character set (or national character set is the column is `nvarchar2`)? It would be easy to test that with a dummy string with simple characters though. Some sample data would be useful, but an example with a much smaller field would be better...

Comment: It was the unicode that caused the issue. I sql trim and replaced all unicodes, export with no issue.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the length of `CHAR` in oracle can be between 1 and 2000 bytes. Perhaps you want to read this [oracle documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821).

Anyway, if the data have variable length, you should consider using `VARCHAR2` instead of `CHAR`. When the data is shorter than specified column length, it will fill the length with spaces.